# Wireless seems to disconnect and reconnect

Tags: 11.10, xubuntu, internet

Whenever I'm browsing or downloading , I'll randomly get these long spikes of no internet connectivity. It only happens in Ubuntu versions like Ubuntu,Xubuntu,Kubuntu and so on. Tried on arch and my internet was fine the whole day. What should I provide?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu (kernel) and what wireless card.

Comment: Running on 3.0.0-16.29 64bit
Wireless card is 01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 (rev 34)

Answer (score 0):

Wireless is influenced by many weird things, like the weather, your neighbor using his network, making a phonecall or using the microwave. You should exclude these factors and try different times without downloading on short distance. Maybe even change wireless channels.

Which drivers do you use for your wireless card on ubuntu? And on arch? 
Are you using a desktop pc or a laptop? In the latter make sure you test from exactly the same location.

Comment: I'm using the default drivers out of the box from ubuntu and I'm not sure what I was running on arch. Are there any online available drivers? I'm using a laptop and both were tested on my bed which is 2 meters away from my router.